# Problem with entire function in a script

Tags: shell-script, solaris, function

I want to detect online network/shell services in my Solaris.
I write following script for this purpose:

```
compare_ser()
{
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
echo "True" >> Solaris.txt
fi
}
export -f compare_ser
svcs network/shell | cut -d ' ' -f1 | grep "online" | xargs -n1 bash -c 'compare_ser $@'
```

when i run `svcs network/shell | cut -d ' ' -f1 | grep "online" | xargs -n1 echo` in terminal, I get the following output:

```
online
online
```

but my script don't show anything.
What's its problem?

Comment: If you're downvoting our answers it would be helpful for us to understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
svcs network/shell | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep "online" | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c 'compare_ser {}'
```

The `{}` interpolates each value generated through `xargs`. Your `$@` attempts to interpolate command line arguments - of which there are none.

Comment: Why the downvote without comment?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, there is a shorter way:

```
svcs network/shell | awk '/online/ {system("bash -c \"compare_ser "$1"\"")}'
```

---

*Dear Downvoters, can you explain your decision? Have you understand, what Linux really is? The script above is a working snippet and maybe there are million ways to do the same. So I ask for an explanation.*

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? Can anyone explain this? Linux is very different but answers here not?

Comment: Drive--by down-vote...  ALL answers were down-voted...  **;-)**

Answer (score -1):

You may have to use double quotes for the string to resolve the positional parameters.

```
svcs network/shell | cut -d ' ' -f1 | grep "online" | xargs -n1 bash -c "compare_ser $@"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
svcs network/shell | sed -n '/^online /c\
True' >> Solaris.txt
```

...should be pretty much the equivalent.

The *reason* your script doesn't show anything, though, is that shell function is shell code which must be executed by a shell which already knows it - the function must first be declared in the shell in which it is run in order to work.

When you call `xargs`, however, you call a program which calls another program, which is a shell, of course, but the new shell processes which `xargs` calls for you are *not* aware of the shell function defined in your current shell.

Of course you do `export -f` which would work, perhaps, if your shell understood what that meant, but if you're using `ksh` on a Solaris system - then it won't. And anyway, that would be a *terribly* inefficient means of reaching your goal if it did.

Comment: I guess this answer was only good enough *not* to get downvoted.

Comment: I guess they changed their mind. It's nice to be noticed.

Comment: export -f worked for me, with a starting point of bash. Perhaps their initial shell was ksh and so the xargs bash subshell couldnt see the function.

Comment: @roima - right,  it should work if launched from `bash`, but `ksh` is the default Solaris shell, and it would not work if run from there.

Comment: @roaima - i guess that depends on version, and on which shell runs what. According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/userenv-1.html), `ksh` is the default scripted shell, but `bash` is the default interactive shell for Solaris 11+. So who knows.